# Products of torsion groups

Tags: infinite-product, torsion-groups

Given an infinite family of non-zero torsion groups $G_i$ (not necessarily commutative). Prove that their Cartesian product is a torsion group iff all but finitely many (i.e. "almost all") of the groups have a finite uniform bound (i.e., there is a positive natural number n with $G_i^n=1$, for all i, except a measly few that may be torsion, unbounded groups). I am pretty sure this is true in the category of Abelian groups, but what about non-commutative groups? 
Added: $G_i^n=1$ means that orders of all elements in $G_i$ divide $n$.

Comment: What do you mean by $G^n_i$?

Comment: Maybe if you try to reason why it's true for abelian groups, you will be able to see if that reason still applies with nonabelian groups.

Comment: @William Stagner, $G_i^n=0$ means that when you raise any element in $G_i$ to n-th power you get the neutral element. But now I see I should have used 1 for the neutral element. Simply orders of all elements of (almost) all these groups divide n. I will correct that.

Comment: @whacka If it were only that easy, although, of course one would think that commutative proof may be part of the general proof. The problem is that I do not know for sure that the claim is true for the non-commutative case.

Comment: Doesn't any finite collection of torsion groups have a uniform bound?

Comment: We are talking about infinite families. Apart of that even a collection of one torsion group need be bounded.

Comment: @WilliamStagner No, even a collection of one torsion group need be bounded. But my interest is in infinite collections, for finite families are trivial

Comment: Re: "of course" one would assume commutativity would be used in the proof... I see no justification for that assumption. Upon trying to prove it for abelian groups, one would notice the proof does *not* invoke commutativity. Don't dismiss an avenue you haven't put thought into.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G = \prod_\alpha G_\alpha$, where $G_\alpha$ are torsion subgroups. It is obvious that if all but finitely many of the $G_\alpha$ have a uniform bound, then $G$ is torsion.

For the other direction, it suffices to show that the product of a countable collection $\{G_i\}_{i\in \mathbb N}$ without a uniform bound is not a torsion group. Let $\{n_i\}_{i\in \mathbb N}$ be an unbounded sequence of natural numbers such that $G_i^{n_i} \neq 1$ for all $i$. For each $i\in \mathbb N$, choose $g_i \in G_i$ such that $g_i^{n_i} \neq 1$. Then the element
$$
(g_1, g_2, \dots) \in \prod_{i \in \mathbb N} G_i
$$
is not torsion.

Comment: Yes, that's right, thanks! Edited.

Comment: @whacka, thanks for reminding me of the avenue I have not put a thought into. Guilty as charged.

Comment: @ william let us see. We want to prove that given any countable collection $G_i, i\in N$, if their product $\prod G_i$ is a torsion group, then, there is a finite subset $J\subset N$, and there is an $n\in N$ such that, $\forall i\in N\setminus J$, $G_i^n=1$. And the proof is "by contradiction" So we need to see how the quantifiers change when we negate the conclusion. Is your proof this kind of contrapositive?

Comment: That's right. The negation of "there exists a finite subset $J \subset \mathbb N$ such that $\{G_i\}_{i\in \mathbb N \setminus J}$ is uniformly bounded" is "for any finite subset $J\subset \mathbb N$, the set $\{G_i\}_{i \in \mathbb N \setminus J}$ is not uniformly bounded."

Comment: Now why would we assume outright that each G_i is bounded at all?

Comment: Certainly if we start with the assumption that all $G_i$ are bounded we have a weaker statement